# Is there a music library player / manager that allows searching for strings in the whole path of music files, not just filenames or ID3 tags?

Tags: software-recommendation, banshee, music-player, clementine, quodlibet

I organized my music, a long time ago, in folders. Searching for a folder's name, for instance "Girlfriend's albums" in Mediamonkey in Windows would show all mp3 files within that folder, and, crucially, within subfolders as well, as long as the searched string was part of the path. I would love to be able to do it on Ubuntu as well, but I never managed to do it.

I tried Clementine, Quodlibet, Rhythmbox, none will index and allow to search within whole paths; in the best scenario, you can search for filenames (Quodlibet).Is there any music player which would allow for this? I will try a few others like Guayadeque and report back, but so far I had no luck.

Comment: until you discover a player based solution issue this from a terminal ( control+alt+t )  while in a parent directory above your music dirs `find . -print | grep -i 'girlfriend' `

Comment: Thanks Scott, that's a smart suggestion; hopefully someone will know a media player that does it. I will give a try to Guayadeque and Lollypop, and then I will probably give up.

Answer (score 2):

I just found out that Quodlibet allows to search within paths, even though it's a bit convoluted. You have to use ~dirname=Girlfriend's in the search field in the case of the example that I gave to find all the music files within that folder and subfolders. It works, but having it active in the default search mode would be better.

EDIT: OK, I'm an idiot. Quodlibet actually does search within whole paths in the default search. It's the only player that I found which does it. My quest is over.